# "A link element must not appear as a descendant of a body element" but not in body

Tags: html, validation, hyperlink

I just checked one HTML page with https://validator.w3.org and got this message:

> Error: A link element must not appear as a descendant of a body element unless the link element has an itemprop attribute or has a rel attribute whose value contains dns-prefetch, modulepreload, pingback, preconnect, prefetch, preload, prerender, or stylesheet.
>
> From line 350, column 3; to line 350, column 56
>
> `ript>  ↩       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />↩     <!-`

I have checked the source HTML code and the link is in the  area (between `<head>` and `</head>` and outside of `<body>` and `</body>`.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Odds are that you **implicitly** closed the head and started the body earlier.

Comment: Most browsers would anyway be indifferent to such errors

Comment: Is the validator having an issue with the link tag having that closing backslash?

Comment: @Quentin: Sorry. It was my first post and perhaps I did something wrong as my intention was to include some code. I think that I've found the solution, but where I am, I have not the resources to give a good explanation. I will do as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more research and found what have happened. Google Analytics, Facebook, and Tweeter have created some code in my page (at my request) and they have made some 'arrangements' in the organization of my page, deleting my  and   tags and writing them some lines before. I wrote:

```
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
-- my scripts ---
</script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>
-- my content ---
```

And inspecting my page I find:

```
<style type="text/css">Facebook CSS</style>
</head>
<body>
&#65279;
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script id="twitter-wjs" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
-- my scripts--
</script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
-- my content --
```

I have solved the issue writing the link just after the meta tags.